# Unable to validate Person<T> object using FluentValidation

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, fluentvalidation

I have code like this

```
public class Person<T>
    {
        public Person()
        {
            Result = default(T);
        }
        public bool IsValid { get; set; }
        public T Result { get; set; }
        public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class PersonValidator<T> : AbstractValidator<Person<T>>
    {
        public PersonValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(r => r.StatusCode).GreaterThan(0);

        }
    }
```

in Startup.cs

```
mvcBuilder.AddFluentValidation(fv => fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining(typeof(PersonValidator<>)));
```

There is no error and error count is coming zero even though rule is not satisfied.

When I remove this `T` from `PersonValidator` and update `AbstractValidator<Person<T>>` to `AbstractValidator<Person<long>>` then it works fine.

I have added validators as `PersonValidator`. Also registered validator as above. I have to validate generic class, please help understand what is going wrong here, and how I can fix it.